# Reversed graph plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I was trying to plot a graph using Python's matplotlib. The data that I wanted to plot is this
[image: the data]

I'm trying to plot `y_i` with respect to `t` (`t` the x axis and `y_i` the y axis), but somehow I ended up with this graph,
[image: graph image here]

You can see that there is something wrong with it, and we all know it (as we go higher along the y axis, the number is getting lower instead of higher). The graph is supposed to have negative slope, how do I fix this? (All kind of help will be appreciated)

Here's my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

e = 2.71828183
k = -0.043594
C = 100
h = 5

def y(t):
    y = C*(e**(k*t))
    return y

def f(Y):
    f = k*Y
    return f

def y_i(Y, F):
    y_i = Y + h*F
    return y_i

#Y = y(x)    
#F = f(Y)
data_luruh = {}
data_luruh['t'] = [x for x in range(0, 101, 5)]
data_luruh['y'] = [y(x) for x in range(0, 101, 5)]
data_luruh['y_i'] = [0 for x in range(0, 101, 5)]
data_luruh['g'] = [0 for x in range(0, 101, 5)]

data_luruh['y_i'][0] = 'NA'
data_luruh['g'][0] = 'NA'

a = 1
while a <= 20:
    data_luruh['y_i'][a] = y_i(y((a-1)*5), f(y((a-1)*5)))
    data_luruh['g'][a] = data_luruh['y'][a] - data_luruh['y_i'][a]
    a += 1

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data_luruh)
print(df)

t_data = data_luruh['t']
y_data = data_luruh['y']
yi_data = data_luruh['y_i']

plt.xlabel('t')
plt.plot(data_luruh['y_i'], 'go')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add NA as a string, the whole data column will be treated as an `object` (the numpy type for strings) column. Thus, the y-column will be sorted lexicographically.

Instead, use `np.nan`, which internally is treated like a number:

```
import numpy as np

data_luruh['y_i'][0] = np.nan
data_luruh['g'][0] = np.nan
```

Comment: You too, thanks for the help. I hope I can do more :).

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `"NA"` for missing values: it's a string and will lead to the other values being interpreted as a string as well. Instead, changing the lines to

```
import numpy as np
data_luruh['y_i'][0] = np.nan
data_luruh['g'][0] = np.nan
```

gives

[image: graph with negative slope]